# Initialize struct with array of n elements

Tags: go

I am trying to implement a matrix in Go.  I have a struct:

```
type Matrix struct {
    n, m int
    rows [][]int
}
```

Currently, rows is just a slice of slices.  Since I know the size of each array I want to store, it seems like I should be able to use arrays of size n and m.  Is there a right way to declare rows to be an array of size n containing arrays of size m before n and m are given values?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to do this. That's the use case of a slice. If you like, you can use one slice of size n*m to save space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Array need fixed, constant size at compile time. If n and/or m are known only at runtime you'll have to go with a slice/slice-of-slices.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the size: http://play.golang.org/p/BPharxQYfL

The simple example above shows how Matrix.row is zero'd out to the size indicated in the type declaration.